# Visualization of scheduling algorithms with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scheduled-tasks

I am looking for a simple way (if possible) to represent the scheduling of a series of task on a cpu like on slide 5  [here](http://rtcc.hanyang.ac.kr/rtccw/wp-content/uploads/download-manager-files/Deferrable_Server_Algo_Aperiodic_RT.pdf).

I would like to have different lines, one for each task, on which I can represent the arrival times, the deadlines and so on. I would like to do it using matplotlib, but at the moment I don't know what is an easy way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with checking the [matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) for similar plots. Here `subplot` seem to be appropriate, thus starting with something like [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/pythonic_matplotlib.html) might be an option.
As you want to remove some spines (axis) you can further check [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/spines_demo_bounds.html).

To get filled blocks I would use a standard `fill_between` or `fill` call with respective data points, see e.g. [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/fill_between_demo.html).

A simple example could be:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cpu1_t = [0,1,1,3,3,4,5]
cpu1_p = [1,1,0,0,1,1,0]
cpu2_t = [0,1,1,3,3,4,5]
cpu2_p = [0,0,1,1,0,0,1]

fig = plt.figure()
# plot 1
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.fill_between(cpu1_t, cpu1_p,0, color='b', edgecolor='k')
ax1.set_ylabel(r'$\tau_1$', size=14, rotation=0)
# plot 2
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax2.fill_between(cpu2_t, cpu2_p,0, color='r', edgecolor='k')
ax2.set_ylabel(r'$\tau_2$', size=14, rotation=0)

# customize axis
for ax in [ax1, ax2]:
    ax.set_ylim(0,2)
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
```

[image]

You can further play with major and minor grids, ticks, etc.
Of course, this is only one possible approach to create such a plot.